# Background image not shown in android phonegap app

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to show a background image on an Android phonegap app using css. This is the sample HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
 </head>
<body style="margin: 0px; background: url("img/bg_index.jpg";) repeat scroll 50% 0px / cover  transparent;">
</body>
</html>
```

**while using this code the background image is not shown in certain android phones such as sony ericsion but in most of the android phones and also in iphone this code is working fine.**

So I tried to change style as shown below

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
 </head>
<body style="margin: 0px;background: url("img/bg_index.jpg";) repeat scroll 50% 0px / cover  transparent; background-image: url("img/bg_index.jpg";);background-repeat:no-repeat;">
</body>
</html>
```

After this style applied the app launched as below in the image [image]

How to write a background style that is accepted by all android devices and iphone

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background: url("../img/bg_index.jpg");
```

Comment: Folder Structure
login.html - www/app/login.html
img - www/app/img
so i think there is no problem with accessing the image

Answer (score 0):

```css
#first-bg {
    background-image: url('http://go.sap.com/_jcr_content/par/hero_a9cf/image.adapt.subtablet.jpg/1426599556769.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
background-image:url('smiley.gif');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
background: url("your/path/img/bg_index.jpg");
```